# Changing Listbox item font color at runtime

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to change a ListBoxItem's font color at runtime. I'm able to change the color with no issue at design time by using the FontColor property, but I need to change the font color at runtime. The example below is not changing the font color.

```
var
    ListBoxItem : TListboxItem;
begin
    ListBoxItem := TlistBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);

    ListBoxItem.Text := Edit1.Text;
    ListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail := Edit2.Text;
    ListBoxItem.StyleLookup := 'listboxitembottomdetail';
    ListBoxItem.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
    ListBoxItem.Height := 34;
    ListBox1.AddObject(ListBoxitem);

end;
```

The code above is supposed to add an item to ListBox1 with the defined color, but it just adds the item with the default font color.

Comment: Add `ListBoxItem.StyledSettings := ListBoxItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is tested for Delphi 10.1 Berlin

In order to change both the normal and detail font color you can make use of the `StyleLookup` property with your own custom style.

At design time in your main form create a `TListBox` and add a `TListBoxItem`.
Go to the `TListBoxItem`'s properties and set the `StyleLookup` to listboxitembottomdetail. After this right click the `TListBoxItem` and choose `Edit custom style...`

Now in the style designer open up the tree `ListBoxItem1Style1`.
Here you will find the text and detail items. There can adjust the font color to whatever you want. **Make sure to save.**

Then after adding the style you can adjust your code to something like this:

```
var
    ListBoxItem : TListboxItem;
begin
    ListBoxItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
    ListBoxItem.Text := Edit1.Text;
    ListBoxItem.ItemData.Detail := Edit2.Text;
    ListBoxItem.StyleLookup := 'ListBoxItem1Style1';
    ListBoxItem.Height := 34;
    ListBox1.AddObject(ListBoxitem);
end;
```